# How to parse a JSON data that has been received by a PHP scipt

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have sent data from my php script using `json_encode' function.

if I `console.log(resp)` below is the O/P I get.

```
data: "{"dept_name":"IT","city_name":"Mumbai","emp_id":"#AC001","emp_name":"Akshay S. Shrivastav"} 
 {"dept_name":"IT","city_name":"Mumbai","emp_id":"#AC003","emp_name":"Aakash Shrivastav"}" status: "success"
```

however, if I `console.log(resp.data)` I get the below data

```
{"dept_name":"IT","city_name":"Mumbai","emp_id":"#AC001","emp_name":"Akshay S. Shrivastav"}{"dept_name":"IT","city_name":"Mumbai","emp_id":"#AC003","emp_name":"Aakash Shrivastav"}
```

Now I'm trying to display this data in the data tables for which I am using the below code.

```
$('#grpList').DataTable().row.add([
        resp.data.dept_name,
        resp.data.city_name,
        resp.data.emp_id,
        resp.data.emp_name
   ]).draw(false);
```

I'm receiving the following error

```
DataTables warning: table id=grpList - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

when I am single handed displaying only `console.log(resp.data.dept_name)` it says `undefined`

I'll be having multiple JSON response if the data increases, for now, I only have two. I'm not able to figure out how to display multiple data using a loop and appending it to the data table.

I'm using below php code to generate JSON

```
$jsonArray = "";
if($data->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row = $data->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $jsonArray .=   json_encode(
                                                array(
                                                        "dept_name" => $row['department_name'],
                                                        "city_name" => $row['city_name'],
                                                        "emp_id" => $row['emp_id'],
                                                        "emp_name" => $row['name']
                                                     ));
            }

        echo json_encode(array("data" => $jsonArray, "status" => 'success'));
    }
```

Comment: As the Jack Bashford answer below says... The json looks like an array of objects... **Even if there is no coma** between the objects... *Possibly only a typo here...* Else that yould make it invalid json. In this case, look on the sever-side to fix that. Also, even if you used `json_encode()` on server-side, it possibly is received a string... Try [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: JSON.parse says `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: Show how you create that json on the server side... `o` possibly is the first letter of "object" in the received string. That would mean you don't need to parse it... But I'm not sure.

Comment: PS: updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on server side.

You define `$jsonArray` as a **string** ! That's wrong.

Try this instead:

```
$jsonArray = [];  // An ARRAY here!
if($data->num_rows > 0)
{
  while($row = $data->fetch_assoc())
  {
  array_push($jsonArray, json_encode(  // Use array_push here
    array(
      "dept_name" => $row['department_name'],
      "city_name" => $row['city_name'],
      "emp_id" => $row['emp_id'],
      "emp_name" => $row['name']
    ));
  }

  echo json_encode(array("data" => $jsonArray, "status" => 'success'));
}
```

**EDIT**
I don't if the above works... Since I did not test it.
But here's how I would have writen it *(I guess you'll have more chances with it)*:

```
$jsonArray = [];
if($data->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {

    // A temp array to rename the one of the keys...
    $tempArray = [];
    $tempArray = ["dept_name"] = $row['department_name'];
    $tempArray = ["city_name"] = $row['city_name'];
    $tempArray = ["emp_id"] = $row['emp_id'];
    $tempArray = ["emp_name"] = $row['name'];

    // Push to the jsonArray now...
    array_push($jsonArray,$tempArray);
  }

  // And finally the result array... To be json encoded
  $result = [];
  $result = ["status"] = "success";
  $result = ["data"] = jsonArray;
  echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Note that without renaming one key and if there's only 4 data per rows from the DB... You could have done `array_push($jsonArray,$row);` directly, without using the `$tempArray`.

So try this... **AND** then apply Jack's answer. ;)

Comment: the temp array worked perfectly and then jack's code worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because `resp.data` is an *array of objects*. You need to get the index first - let's say index `0`, or the first object in the array:

```
$("#grpList").DataTable().row.add([
  resp.data[0].dept_name,
  resp.data[0].city_name,
  resp.data[0].emp_id,
  resp.data[0].emp_name
]).draw(false);
```

And if you want the second object:

```
$("#grpList").DataTable().row.add([
  resp.data[1].dept_name,
  resp.data[1].city_name,
  resp.data[1].emp_id,
  resp.data[1].emp_name
]).draw(false);
```

Of course, [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) accepts an array argument as well - so this would work too:

```
$("#grpList").DataTable().row.add(resp.data).draw(false);
```

Comment: still the same error. PS I've modified the questions so that you can also see the actual array without any segregation.

Comment: the 1st code worked after using @Louys Patrice Bessette modified PHP script. But, `$("#grpList").DataTable().row.add(resp.data).draw(false);` is not accepting `resp.data` or `resp.data[0]`. can u suggest me an alternate solution.